# c# regex - changing pattern matches until find specific word

Tags: c#, regex

usually i can workaround and get everything works by myself, but this one is kinda tricky, even msdn references and examples confuses more than helps.
i have testing some codes and stuck at mixing a capture grouping for changing with a non-capturing group, to stop the matchings when i wish

a simpler code that i want to change is:

```
stats = "label:100,value:7878,label:110,value:7879,something,label:200,value:8888";

valor = "value:8080";
```

i know if i use

```
pattern = @"value:(\d+)";
```

i can change every value number to 8080 when i do

```
Regex.Replace(stats, pattern, valor);
```

but i need he stops changing these when find 'something' string

i managed to change every single char to 'valor' until he finds 'something' using

```
pattern = @"^(?:(?!something).)*";
```

is there a way to only change 'value:(\d+)' numbers to 'valor' , along with the ?:(?!something) to stop the matchings in the same sentence?
ive seen lots of examples but they never said something like this so i dunno if its possible to merge both conditions at same time

Comment: Your data is delimited by a comma, so I see a rather trivial non-regex approach to doing this.  Regex is what you asked for, so @stribizhev answer will do it for you.

Comment: sup bro, i used a simple example in a language i can test, but im going to export the logic to a tool that doesnt allow me to run a script to get the same effect, aside from manual changing every value, only regex parameters is available for me atm... thx for reply

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a look-behind solution that makes sure there is no `something` before the value:

```
(?<!\bsomething\b.*)value:\d+
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5cbsomething%5cb.*)value%3a%5cd%2b&i=label%3a100%2cvalue%3a7878%2clabel%3a110%2cvalue%3a7879%2csomething%2clabel%3a200%2cvalue%3a8888&r=value%3a8080&o=r&s=62)

Note that `something` is matched as a whole word due to `\b` word boundaries.

The result of replace operation:

[image]

Note that `(?:(?!something).)` is very inefficient and should be used when no other means works. In .NET, there is a powerful variable-width look-behind, which is the right tool for this task.

Also note that if you are not using capture group backreferences, you do not need those capturing groups in your pattern (I remove parentheses from around `\d+`).

Comment: i see, im in need of understanding better all the capabilities of assertions, the ?: was a code ive found in another example, your answer helps a lot because i have something to work on, testing and so... many thanks ma friend

Comment: The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, not a zero-width assertion, like look-behinds or look-aheads. It will consume text and will return it as part of the match. The look-around will only check for the string presence/absence and will return either true or false, thus either allowing or failing the match. Please feel free to drop comments if anything is still unclear.